# How to write tensorflow events to google cloud storage from Docker container inside VM instance

Tags: python, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, tensorflow2.0

I've created a VM instance on Google Compute Engine. After uploading my project and building my image, I ran into my container and authorized access to Google Cloud Platform with my service account:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account test@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=mykey.json
```

so that I can access my google cloud storage (I did a test with `gsutil cp` on my bucket and it works). Now I try to execute a tensorflow python script like this:

```
python object_detection/model_main_tf2.py \
  --pipeline_config_path=/raccoon/config.config \
  --model_dir=gs://my-bucket/ \
  --num_train_steps=10
```

specifying as model_dir my bucket so that checkpoints and events are stored there (in order to monitor the progress of the training with tensorboard from my laptop).

Problem is I get the following permission error from tensorflow:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.PermissionDeniedError: 
Error executing an HTTP request: HTTP response code 
403 with body '{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Insufficient Permission",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Insufficient Permission",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
      }
    ]
  }
}
'
when initiating an upload to gs://my-bucket/train/events.out.tfevents.1601998426.266
1f74c3966.450.2928.v2
        Failed to flush 1 events to gs://my-bucket/train/events.out.tfevents.1601998426.2661f
74c3966.450.2928.v2
        Flushing first event.
        Could not initialize events writer. [Op:CreateSummaryFileWriter]
```

The `train` directory exists on my bucket and as I said before the following command is working:

```
gsutil cp test.txt gs://my-bucket/train/.
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authenticating `gcloud` just ensures that future `gcloud` commands are authenticated. Your script (likely) doesn't use `gcloud` and thus isn't authenticated.

Instead, if you have service account credentials in a JSON file, you can specify it via the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to have TensorFlow be able to read/write to GCS via `gs://` URLs.

Comment: Thanks Dustin for the explanations. After exporting the variable (in my container), it works.